# Flutter/Dart - Trying to iterate over a map of values // Syntax help needed

Tags: flutter, loops, dart

I'm a self-learning beginner at coding, failing at a self-set task. The aim of the task is ultimately to figure out the syntax...but I spent hours now. So...help pls! Warning: I thoroughly confused myself...so don't expect beauty in my attempt.

I want to use iterate over this map:

```
const marginsCard = [
  {
    'ID': 0,
    'margins': [
      {'marginLeft': 0},
      {'marginRight': 5},
      {'marginBottom': 0},
      {'marginTop': 20},
    ],
  },
  {
    'ID': 1,
    'margins': [
      {'marginLeft': 5},
      {'marginRight': 0},
      {'marginBottom': 0},
      {'marginTop': 20,},
    ],
  },
  {
    'ID': 2,
    'margins': [
      {'marginLeft': 5},
      {'marginRight': 0},
      {'marginBottom': 0},
      {'marginTop': 20,},
    ],
  },
];
```

The goals are to

1. iterate over 'ID'
2. hand over the values for the margins to  a constructor method that
3. hand back a Card with the specified margins
4. put those Cards in a list.

The function calling the constructor function in its current state:

```
buildCardElementList(){

  cardElementsList = [
  ...(marginsCard[int.parse('ID')] as List<Map<String,Object>>).map((cardElement){
    return buildCardElement(cardElement['marginLeft'], cardElement['marginRight'], cardElement['marginBottom'], cardElement['marginTop']);
  }).toList()];
  return cardElementsList;
}
```

There is so much try and eror in this, I'm sure there are multiple issues. Can someone help me out with clean syntax so I can start to understand what I'm doing again?

Thanks!

EDIT // P.S.: I'm leaving out the receiving/constructing function; it's not the issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Enjoy ;)

```dart
void main() {
  final cards = marginsCard.map(_buildCard).toList();
  print(cards);
}

Card _buildCard(Map<String, Object> cardElement) {
  return Card(
    marginLeft: resolveMargin(cardElement, 'marginLeft'),
    marginRight: resolveMargin(cardElement, 'marginRight'),
    marginBottom: resolveMargin(cardElement, 'marginBottom'),
    marginTop: resolveMargin(cardElement, 'marginTop'),
  );
}

num resolveMargin(Map<String, Object> cardElement, String marginName) {
  final marginElements = cardElement['margins'] as List<Map<String, Object>>;
  return marginElements.firstWhere((marginElement) => marginElement.containsKey(marginName))[marginName] as num;
}

class Card {
  final num marginLeft, marginRight, marginBottom, marginTop;
  Card({required this.marginLeft, required this.marginRight, required this.marginBottom, required this.marginTop});
  
  @override
  String toString() => "marginLeft: $marginLeft; marginRight: $marginRight; marginBottom: $marginBottom; marginTop: $marginTop";
}

const marginsCard = [
  {
    'ID': 0,
    'margins': [
      {'marginLeft': 0},
      {'marginRight': 5},
      {'marginBottom': 0},
      {'marginTop': 20},
    ],
  },
  {
    'ID': 1,
    'margins': [
      {'marginLeft': 5},
      {'marginRight': 0},
      {'marginBottom': 0},
      {'marginTop': 20,},
    ],
  },
  {
    'ID': 2,
    'margins': [
      {'marginLeft': 5},
      {'marginRight': 0},
      {'marginBottom': 0},
      {'marginTop': 20,},
    ],
  },
];
```

Comment: Thanks, at least I have something to chew on that works ;)